# How to delete the last column in an HTML TABLE using by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML TABLE:

```
<table id="persons" border="1">
    <thead id="theadID">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>sex</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyID">
        <tr>
            <td>Viktor</td>
            <td>Male</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Melissa</td>
            <td>Female</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Male</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="deleteLastColumn();" value="do it"/>
```

I need a javascript/jquery code, which delete the last column (message) in the table:

```
function deleteLastColumn() {
    $("#theadID tr th:not(:last-child)......
    $("#tbodyID tr td:not(:last-child)......
}
```

So the result should be this:

```
<table id="persons" border="1">
    <thead id="theadID">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>sex</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyID">
        <tr>
            <td>Viktor</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Melissa</td>
            <td>Female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Male</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know there is the ":not(last)" method, but I can't find any example to my problem.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
$('#persons tr').find('th:last-child, td:last-child').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gnCtF/)

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks a Bunch!

Comment: All this does for me is make all the values inside the last Td elements equal to zero, and not removing it completely.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this solution to achieve it easily..

```js
function myFunction() {
  var allRows = document.getElementById('my_table').rows;
 for (var i=0; i< allRows.length; i++) {
   allRows[i].deleteCell(-1); 
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table id="my_table">
  <thead >
    <th>Column 1</td>
    <th>Column 2</td>
    <th>Column 3</td>
  </thead >
  <tr >
    <td>Number 1</td>
    <td>String 1</td>
    <td>Decimal 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>Number 2</td>
    <td>String 2</td>
    <td>Decimal 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
     <td>Number 3</td>
    <td>String 3</td>
    <td>Decimal 3</td>
  </tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Remove Last Column</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Arun P Johny's answer,

That would let you remove last row each time you click the button. If you just want to remove one column, not others you may try this.

```
function deleteLastColumn() {
    $(document).find('.last').remove()
}
```

after adding class `last` to the last `td` and `th` of the table.

Demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnCtF/3/)